# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I had a [question put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35363822/1091116) that was asking about programming practices, which does not seem to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource*. Why would that be off-topic?

Comment: Sounds primarily opinion-based to me.

Comment: @MartinJames It asks if there is a standard place; I believe that makes it objectively answerable.

Comment: It may have been closed for the wrong reason, but it's not worth re-opening if we're just gonna reclose it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth who decides what the "standard place" is? from my point of view that just sounds like "best practice"

Comment: @KevinB Usually the people who make the product; e.g. javadoc for Java classes and methods. And sometimes the answer is simply "no, there is no standard place to put the documentation".

Comment: I would assume the close voters were interpreting "Is there a standard place" as looking for a website where you should post your documentation. If you were asking "Where in the codebase should I put it", a simple edit should make that clear.

Comment: I don't think the close reason chosen fits this case, but i do think it's primarily opinion based. If it isn't primarily opinion based, then a large number of best practice questions are incorrectly closed.

Comment: @BSMP That's just making the question a statement of someone else's opinion.  Not really the kind of thing that really makes sense being on SO.

Comment: It is sad that most of the community would prefer to entertain "debug my code" questions just because they meet some arbitrary "objectivity" standard. Your question looks fine to me. You aren't asking for an off-site reference, you're looking for expert guidance on how to accomplish a specific programming task. There might be a couple of different answers with different perspectives, but that's nothing to worry about. It's certainly not like your question is so broad that it can't be answered by a single answer, nor so broad that it could have *infinitely many* answers. I voted to re-open.